# Finder cannot see any files on NTFS mount

Tags: terminal, finder, homebrew, file, ntfs

I installed osxfuse and ntfs-3g and it worked well till today to read NTFS partitions.
Since today, after brew upgrade yesterday, Finder cannot see any file in NTFS root or folders, though they show up in terminal.
And asking Jdownloader2 to open a file downloaded on the NTFS partition  invokes openanyfile on that file instead of the default application for that file type, it works if supported.
I see macfuse is installed too, maybe from brew upgrade ? To solve the issue I uninstalled macfuse, ntfs-3g and osxfuse, and the files show up again in Finder (but not writable). Then I reinstalled osxfuse and ntfs-3g (I got `Warning: ntfs-3g has been deprecated because it requires FUSE!` from Brew), reboot, and I get the same issue again : files not showing up in Finder but with Terminal it works.

Version is Catalina 10.15.3

Any idea how I could solve this issue ?

Comment: My understanding that osxfuse is a problem with recent macOS. And brew info ntfs-3g tells me that ntfs-3g is now 4 yrs old.  I suspect the answer to your question is "Paragon", but you probably don't want to hear that.

Comment: @Gilby well, I installed the trial version of Paragon and it is true that it solved the issue...

Comment: Glad that it works for you.  And Paragon is cheaper than it used to be (if my memory is right).